# Why is the SQL query from Entity Framework not visible in the profiler?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Consider this piece of code:

```
var question = context.Questionnaires.FirstOrDefault(q => q.id == 169).Categories.ToList()[1].Questions.ToList()[0];
```

This is just some excerise code for me to get familiar on how EF works. So for that reason I have created a few tables. Questionnaire with a reference to Category and the Category has a reference to Question.

What I notice here when I execute this code, I see in the profiler only the select statement of the questionnaire. But i am wondering, where is the query to get all the categories and questions? I can't find this query? I assume this must be visible in the profiler, right?

EDIT:
this is what I can get from the profiler:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[actualFrom] AS [actualFrom], 
[Extent1].[name] AS [name], 
[Extent1].[version] AS [version], 
[Extent1].[startDate] AS [startDate], 
[Extent1].[endDate] AS [endDate], 
[Extent1].[description] AS [description], 
[Extent1].[createdOn] AS [createdOn], 
[Extent1].[createdBy] AS [createdBy], 
[Extent1].[showQuestionCode] AS [showQuestionCode], 
[Extent1].[font] AS [font], 
[Extent1].[removed] AS [removed], 
[Extent1].[showAchievementsAppointmentTab] AS [showAchievementsAppointmentTab], 
[Extent1].[showConceptTabs] AS [showConceptTabs], 
[Extent1].[f_QuestionnaireBuilder_QuestionnaireType_Id] AS [f_QuestionnaireBuilder_QuestionnaireType_Id], 
[Extent1].[f_QuestionnaireBuilder_Status_Id] AS [f_QuestionnaireBuilder_Status_Id], 
[Extent1].[f_QuestionnaireBuilder_Questionnaire_ParentId] AS [f_QuestionnaireBuilder_Questionnaire_ParentId], 
[Extent1].[f_QuestionnaireBuilder_QuestionnaireCategory_Id] AS [f_QuestionnaireBuilder_QuestionnaireCategory_Id], 
[Extent1].[f_Careplan_VisionModel] AS [f_Careplan_VisionModel]
FROM [implementation].[QuestionnaireBuilder_Questionnaire] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 169 = [Extent1].[id]
```

Comment: can you show the SELECT you were able to sniff with the Profiler?

Comment: setting the profiler aside for a second, does this code return the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have lazy loading enabled?

If lazy loading is **not** enabled, I think your C# line will throw an exception. The only time the database is hit is at the call to **FirstOrDefault**. The returned **Questionnaire** will have an empty collection of **Categories** because you did not include them in the original query. So, requesting an index of **1** should throw an exception.

If lazy loading **is** enabled, then the line should work, but it will result in multiple queries hitting the database. The first will be at the call to **FirstOrDefault**, the second will be at the conversion of **Categories** to a list, and the third will be at the conversion of **Questions** to a list.

So, if you have lazy loading enabled, check the profiler for additional queries after the one you posted.

You might try this, if lazy loading is disabled:

```
var question = context.Questionnaires.
               Include("Categories.Questions").
               FirstOrDefault(q => q.id == 169).
               Categories.ToList()[1].
               Questions.ToList()[0];
```

Here's a short blog post with some more information. [Getting Started with Entity Framework 4 – Lazy Loading](http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2009/11/26/getting-started-with-entity-framework-4-ndash-lazy-loading.aspx)

Comment: THnx, lazy loading is enabled. When I look better I saw that other queries were send using a RPC request, while the first rewuest was a plain sql command.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the root cause of your problem but remove the .ToList() calls.  instead of an indexer, use .ElementAt().  ToList stops the query from being executed as a SQL query and instead switches you to Linq-to-Objects